# Java - Is it possible to have a subclass constructor only 1 parameter, that doesn't involve calling super()?

Tags: java, abstract-class, super, class-constructors

Here is my abstract class:

```
public abstract class BankAccount{
  protected long balance;

  public BankAccount(long balance){ \\<--Abstract class constructor
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  ... more stuff
}
```

I have the following subclass (also an extra subclass SavingsAccount, they both have their own independent balance, but's that's irrelevant):

```
public class CurrentAccount extends BankAccount{
  private int PIN;
  private long overdraft = 0;
  private long balance;

  // Set balance and overdraft and the PIN
  public CurrentAccount(long balance, long overdraft, int PIN){
    super(balance);
    this.overdraft = overdraft;
    setPIN(PIN);
  }


  // Set balance and overdraft
  public CurrentAccount(long balance, long overdraft){
    super(balance);
    this.overdraft = overdraft;
  }

  // Set overdraft only
  public CurrentAccount(long overdraft){  \\<-- is it possible to have something like this?
    super(balance);
    this.overdraft = overdraft;
  }

  public void setPIN(int PIN){
    if(PIN >= 0000 && PIN <= 9999){ 
      this.PIN = PIN;
    }
  }

  ... more methods
}
```

As you can see from above, I want a constructor that just sets the overdraft, but I still need to call super at the start of every constructor, so I'm just passing in, whatever the balance currently is, can I even do that? Or do I need a balance variable in my CurrentAccount subclass aswell?

When compiling java is giving me this:

```
CurrentAccount.java:41: error: cannot reference balance before supertype constructor has been called
    super(balance);
          ^
1 error
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If parent class doesn't have a default (no arguments) constructor then this means that ***by design*** the class must be initialized with a `balance` value.

This implies that there is no way to do what you are tying to do, unless initializing it with a default value (eg `super(0)`).

The error is given by the fact that you are accessing a field of the super class before actually constructing it, which is the first thing you must do in a subclass.

Comment: If I create a no argument constructor, shouldn't it do something? And if I make it do something useless , like set a pointless variable to 0, then will that be bad programming?

Comment: @Physco111: it's all a matter of design. Does it make sense to create a `BankAccount` without specifying an initial balance (which would default to 0)? If the answer is yes then you can provide a no-args constructor which intializes it to 0.

Comment: Alright thank you, I'd say your answer made the most the sense to me.

Comment: Specifically the error is caused by the fact that while in all the other constructors the unqualified name `balance` refers to a local variable due to shadowing, in the last constructor there is no such local variable, and thus the name refers to the field of the superclass, which is not allowed at that point.